# Why does a new Gradle build start whenever I run Espresso tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

Whenever I attempt to run an Espresso test from Android Studio (typically by right-clicking on a test/class/package and selecting 'Run All Tests'), Android Studio kicks off a new build and installs a new APK even when no changes were made. Naturally, this makes debugging failing UI tests a very time consuming procedure. Has anyone encountered this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Android Instrumented Unit Test should put test java files in app/src/androidTest/java/your.package.name directory, not test folder
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: My tests are in the androidTest directory, so that's probably not the issue.